# How to fail sonarqube quality code if code coverage in new code is less than overall code?

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to add a quality gate in sonarqube, to fail if the new code coverage % drops below the overall code coverage.
Anyone have tried this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to be more specific.  I'm not sure what "overall" means.  Are you referring to the "after merge" value?  It's also unclear whether you're referring to a "base project" or a pull request or branch.

If you're looking to ensure that the "after merge" coverage on a branch scan satisfies a required threshold, I'm pretty sure you can't do that out of the box with SonarQube, but you should also specify what version of SonarQube you're using.

I implemented a check for whether the "after merge" coverage value of a branch scan satisfies our required threshold, but I had to do it in script code, using the SonarQube Web API.  I had it obtain the project's quality gate, along with the resulting coverage from the scan, and if it's below the required number, I have it fail the build with an appropriate message.  There's no way to mark the scan itself to be in violation, but at least we can make the build fail.